# Export/Import of Chrome App History

Tags: postman

With the deprecation of the Postman Chrome App I am looking to transfer to the native app.  However I have extensive history in the chrome app.  Is there a quick way to transfer history between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your history with [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1647#issuecomment-341270254) hack, but to import the data you have to insert stuff into native app's sqlite db. Another way is to select all reqs in history and then save them into a collection that you can import.